# Hibernate statistic TransactionCount vs SuccessfulTransactionCount

Tags: hibernate

I have enabled hibernate statistic on my application. Through JConsole.exe I found the following entries

```
TransactionCount = 62
SuccessfulTransactionCount = 31
```

TransactionCount value reflects the total of transactions while SuccessfulTransactionCount reflects the successful transaction. Does this mean that there were 31 failed transactions ?

Comment: Seems like an old weirdness : https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=951490

Comment: Maybe a partial explanation : http://www.coderanch.com/t/216948/ORM/databases/Double-transaction-counts-Hibernate-Statistics